# How to add when argument is passed as Generic ArrayList<?>

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a function which takes a generic `ArrayList<?>` as one of the parameters and what I've found is that I get a Java error when I try to use the add method of the `ArrayList`

> no suitable method found for add(MyClass)

What I am trying to accomplish is pass parameters for a Class and an ArrayList and have the function populate the ArrayList with objects of the Class. Though if I could instead create and return the ArrayList from my function, that would be fine too (one less parameter would be nice).

Here is some code to illustrate how I am currently trying to go about this:

```
public void myFunction(Class clazz, ArrayList<?> myList)
{
  Object myObject=null;
  try{myObject = clazz.newInstance();}catch(Exception e){}      
  myList.add(myObject);
}
```

... or maybe something like this:

```
public ArrayList<?> myFunction(Class clazz)
{
  ArrayList<clazz> myList = new ArrayList<clazz>();
  Object myObject=null;
  try{myObject = clazz.newInstance();}catch(Exception e){}      
  myList.add(myObject);
}
```

If someone could please:

a) show me some code that does this
 b) explain how to accomplish my goal using Generics
 or c) just let me know where I'm going wrong and provide an alternate way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first method can be fixed as:

```
public <T>
void myFunction(Class<T> clazz, ArrayList<T> myList) {
    T myObject = null;
    try {
        myObject = clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    myList.add(myObject);
}
```

The second one as:

```
public <T>
ArrayList<T> myFunction(Class<T> clazz) {
    ArrayList<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>();
    T myObject = null;
    try {
        myObject = clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    myList.add(myObject);
    return myList;
}
```

Here `T` is called a type parameter. You can use any letter or identifier instead of `T`.

Comment: Thanks. This does exactly what I need. I was able to re-work my code by following the methods you provided.

Answer (score 4):

in order to add something to ArrayList, you need to make it's type definition contravariant.

So something like

```
public <T> void doSomething(...,List<? super T> args,...)
```

would work.

Comment: Does T stand for Type in this case?

Comment: T is placeholder for the type, which makes method generic

Comment: Thanks, this was along the right path I think. I don't yet have a firm grasp on Generics but I'm getting there.

Comment: With generics you may do lots of fun, just remembering simple rule - covariance allows you to return specific type **from** method call, and contravariance allows you to pass something specific **into** method call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ArrayList<Object>` instead, this will allow you to add objects to your list. As for [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), it's hard to say how you go about using it without seeing the entirety of your code.

```
public List<?> myFunction(Class clazz) {
    List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Object o = clazz.newInstance();
    l.add(o);
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I need the ArrayList to stay generic so that I can cast it to the appropriate type when it comes out of the function.

Comment: If it comes to that, I'll definitely post the code. Just trying to keep my post as unspecific as possible but still to the point.

Comment: Further and to clarify: I want to know if it's possible to retain the type of List that is passed in to the function. If I were to use a List<Object> as a container, I would have to later loop through the List<Object> and cast each object to get my List<MyClass>.